# How to put input text and 2 buttons in the modal footer?

Tags: html

I want to have an input text with 2 buttons beside of it in the modal footer, those 2 buttons must have the same height with the input text, how to show it properly?

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#chatModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="chatModal" class="modal fade" data-coreui-backdrop="static" data-coreui-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-gradient-success">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal_title">Chat</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">We are working on it, please try again later</div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="row justify-content-lg-between">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input class="form-control" id="message" type="text" name="message" maxlength="1024" placeholder="Message" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
                        <button id="btnChatClose" onclick="hideChatModal();" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Exit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `tag` wrap 2 button and set `d-flex` `justify-content-center`:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#chatModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="chatModal" class="modal fade" data-coreui-backdrop="static" data-coreui-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-gradient-success">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal_title">Chat</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">We are working on it, please try again later</div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-lg-between">
                    <div class="col-md-8 mx-5">
                        <input class="form-control" id="message" type="text" name="message" maxlength="1024" placeholder="Message" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-lg-center">
                    <div class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 text-right">
                        <button id="btnChatClose" onclick="hideChatModal();" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Exit</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```